# AFNetworking + Reactive Cocoa non blocking loading, do not repeat request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, reactive-cocoa

I would like to fire a network request with opening a view controller to fetch some data, so far nothing special. The user should not be blocked a annoying loading spinner, so it will still be possible to navigate in the app

What I would like to implement is : when the user pops the current view controller and comes back again, the request should not fire again if the previous call is not completed, but it should still take into account the completion blocks.

Is this doable with reactive cocoa?

I'm using [this](https://github.com/knshiro/AFNetworking-RACExtensions) to use AFNetworking with Reactive Cocoa